# Third Party Mini Display Port to VGA or DVI Cables

Tags: macbook-pro

curious if anyone has any experience with any third party Mini Display Port to VGA or DVI cables? I noticed the cables on *ebay* selling for around $16. Compared to the **official** cables that run for around $35 seems like a bargin. Wasn't sure if the quality is the same or if anyone has any experience with buying them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most third-party cables will work perfectly.  In particular, any cables which are digital should perform exactly as their more expensive counterparts.  I've personally used a couple of third party cables which worked without issue.

I bought a Mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable when the MacBook Pro 13" Unibody first came out from [www.circuitassembly.com](http://estore.circuitassembly.com/categories/Adapters/Mini-Displayport/) and it's great quality and was cheap too

Comment: No worries, I just updated the link to point to the Mini DisplayPort section since that's what you're interested in ;o)

Answer (score 4):

The cables from Monoprice.com have recently changed so they're not shaped as nicely as before, but the quality is still excellent for the price. 6ft cable for $10 shipped.

http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024604&p_id=5999&seq=1&format=2

The picture isn't faithful to what you'll receive as the Mini Display Port male plug is now a bit bulkier. Still works flawlessly though.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not shaped as nicely. The ones I found on eBay looked identical to the Apple version (I was fooled until I read the small text). The price can't be beat though! Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

A cheap knockoff Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter in I bought on eBay for $7 worked pretty well, but caused a strange problem on my rMBP. Occasionally, when using it, my Wi-Fi would cut out, and switching to an Apple adapter fixed the issue.

I tested this six ways to Sunday, and the cheap adapter was definitely the consistent factor. It's a weird issue, but [apparently I'm not the only one](http://www.techerator.com/2010/10/fix-apples-mini-displayport-wireless-internet-connection-problem/).

Answer (score 0):

We got several mini-display port to DVI, VGA and HDMI cables from http://www.meritline.com/ and they work great.  In particular, they have a mini-displayport to hdmi, dvi and displayport (all in one) dongle.